# Can I create a yasnippet with a repeating variable length list

Tags: yasnippet

Javascript Angular has a peculiar pattern for creating controllers that looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'foo', 'bar', 
                 function($scope, foo, bar) {
                     //do stuff...
                 }]);
```

The `'$scope', 'foo', 'bar'` thing is repeated as the parameter list in the function inside the square-bracketed array.

I thought I could make doing this less error-prone by writing a yasnippet. It looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: angctl
# key: angctl
# --
$1.controller('$2', ['$3', function($3) {
$0;
}]);
```

This works fine, but only if there is one parameter (in the $3 position), like if I'm just using `$scope`. If I want to use more than one, it breaks down.

Is there some way of writing the snippet so it will make a comma delimited list of quoted strings and repeat a comma delimited list of unquoted strings somewhere else within the snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess something like this might work:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: angctl
# key: angctl
# --
$1.controller('$2', [${3:$(mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "'%s'" x))
                                     (split-string yas-text "," t "[ \t]") ", ")}, function($3) {
$0;
}])
```

And in action:

[image]